# Why can't a bind linux service to the loop-back only?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, posix

I am writing a server application that will provide a service on an ephemeral port that I only want accessible on the loopback interface.  In order to do this, I am writing code like the following:

```
struct sockaddr_in bind_addr;

memset(&bind_addr,0,sizeof(bind_addr));
bind_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bind_addr.sin_port = 0;
bind_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(inet_addr("127.0.0.1"));
rcd = ::bind(
   socket_handle,
   reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(&bind_addr),
   sizeof(bind_addr));
```

The return value for this call to bind() is -1 and the value of errno is 99 (Cannot assign requested address).  Is this failing because inet_addr() already returns its result in network order or is there some other reason?

Comment: I should have done some more experiments before posting.  It would appear that inet_addr() already returns the address in network order.

Comment: instead of making experiments, you could read the man page. It says that inet_addr doesn't do any decent error checking, and that there is already a constant defined in netinet/in.h called INADDR_LOOPBACK that is exactly what you want.

Comment: @BatchyX: That constant is nonstandard (not specified in POSIX).

Comment: @R.: it is nonstandart, but it exists on BSD, Linux, Mac OSX, Solaris, and Windows, and only the "linux" tag was set by the asker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this failing because inet_addr() already returns its result in network order

Yes.

So remove the htonl call.

Comment: `INADDR_LOOPBACK` is a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 4):

`inet_addr` should be avoided, for there is a much saner method of constructing `struct sockaddr`s (which means it also obsoletes `gethostby*`):

```
#include <netdb.h>

/* Error checking omitted for brevity */
struct addrinfo hints = {.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE};
struct addrinfo *res;
getaddrinfo("::1", NULL, &hints, &res); /* or 127.0.0.1 if you are 60+ */
bind(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
freeaddrinfo(res);
```