# How do sockets handle local address changes?

Tags: c, sockets

In C, I can bind a client socket to a specific local address and a system-selected port. What would happen if any of the following happened?

1. The local address of the machine is changed
2. The program is moved to a host with a different local address

And what would happen if I attempt to bind after calling connect()?

Comment: Use localhost loopback IP address "127.0.0.1" and Port Number combination for creating the socket . Because loopback address does not change.  [link] ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411205/client-server-connection-on-loopback-interface)

Comment: What do you mean "moved to a host"?

Comment: @PKumarasamy: *"Use localhost loopback IP address "127.0.0.1""*  which means that you will only be able to communicate with anything on the local machine and not with anything in the network. Not very useful in most use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in general, a TCP socket connection is really identified by the source IP, source port, destination ip, destination port tuple. If say the source IP is not valid any more then neither end can recover from it and the destination host will not probably notice until after a timeout.

If on the other hand you're trying to bind to an address that is not local at that time, the bind system call should return an error (`EADDRNOTAVAIL`).

Finally, rebinding a connected TCP socket should result in an error because it doesn't make any sense.